# Invoking .find() on empty array leads to error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on small app and sometimes my array `productTypes` has data, and sometimes it doesn't..

And I've noticed when there's no data my app throwing errors. Here is my code:

```
 renderer: row =>
 row.data.productType && productTypes.find(x => x.key === row.data.productType).value
```

How could I avoid checking this code:

```
&& productTypes.find(x => x.key === row.data.productType).value
```

if `productTypes` is empty array.. because obliviously that would avoid errors..

Thanks

Comment: Trying to `find` something in an empty array won't throw an error. You don't need to guard against `productTypes` being empty, you need to guard against `productTypes` being undefined, null, or against `find` coming up empty.

Comment: He is trying to access a property of undefined. in this case he needs to guard against empty arrays

Comment: That's what I meant by "guard against `find` coming up empty".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is returning `undefined`.

```
productTypes.find(x => x.key === row.data.productType)
```

Test if `length` is different from 0

```
productTypes.length && productTypes.find(x => x.key === row.data.productType).value
```

Or do something like this

```
row =>{
    const item = productTypes.find(x => x.key === row.data.productType)

     return row.data.productType item && item.value
}
```

To a custom message you can use `ternary operators`

```
productTypes.length ? productTypes.find(x => x.key === row.data.productType).value : 'Not Available'
```

Comment: this works but what if I want to display "Not availble" instead of just avoid error, how could we add string here? for example we checks for length and its 0 and we avoided error but lets display some message?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.find()` returns `undefined` if nothing is found. And `undefined` does not have the property `.value`. The quick solution is to provide a fallback inside the expression:

```
 renderer: row =>
 row.data.productType && ( productTypes.find(x => x.key === row.data.productType) || { value: null }).value
```

This will return null if the `row.data.productType` is not `.find()`ed ( found ) inside `productType`.

This also protects again `productTypes` having multiple items, but not the item with the correct `key`, something just checking the length of `productTypes` won't help with.

Comment: Nice use of `||`

Comment: Personally I really dislike this notation, but since the OP is already using `&&`, I thought it was appropriate here. I would just go for an if/else inside the function body to make it easier to read what the intention of the code is.